# How to execute next command after Launch Android emulator from command line using shell script?

Tags: android, shell, android-emulator

I am a newbie in Shell script programming, and maybe you can help me with my query.

My requirement is in Android app build, launch emulator and install the ".apk" into emulator from command line for that I need to write a shell script in which I am able to build, install and run the app in emulator from the command line by individual command, but when i try to integrate those commands into a shell script, emulator taking the control when launching, no commands (install and run) are working after that. can you tell me how sort out this issue

Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add "&" symbol after emulator line command.
`>command1 &`
`>command2`

This makes `command1` to go to background, and `command2` can be run.